# Nth root of positive semidefinite operator over a Hilbert space.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, spectral-theory, self-adjoint-operators

> Prove that every positive semidefinite operator $T\in B(\mathcal{H})$, where $\mathcal{H}$ is an infinite dimensional Hilbert space, has a unique positive-semidefinite $n$th root for every $n\in\Bbb{N}$.

My idea was to use the Spectral theorem - I know that since $T$ is positive semidefinite, it's self adjoint and its spectrum $\sigma(T)\subseteq[0,\infty)$. Since it's self adjoint, there exists a projection - valued measure $P_T$ s.t $$T=\int_{\sigma(T)} tdP_T$$
I want to show (or atleast I suspect it to be true) that $$\sqrt[n]{T}=\int_{\sigma(T)} \sqrt[n]{t}dP_T$$
Which is well defined since $\sigma(T)\subseteq [0,\infty)$. Anyway, I didn't know exactly where to start (or even if this is true). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See if your proposed definition satisfies that its $n$th power is $T$.  It should work very easily.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith Thing is, $f(x)=\sqrt[n]{x}$ is not a bounded borel function, so I'm not sure that $f(T)=\int f(t)dP_T$

Comment: Use instead the function $f(x) = x^{1/n}$ if $x \le \rho(T)$, and $0$ (or anything you like) if $x > \rho(T)$, where $\rho(T)$ is the spectral radius of $T$.  In other words, $f$ only has to be bounded on the spectrum of $T$.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith I'm still not a $100$ percent sure how to show the result though. I defined $S=f(T)$ and fixed $u,v\in\mathcal{H}$. Am I supposed to show that $\langle S^nu,v\rangle=\langle(\int f(t)dP_T)^nu,v\rangle=\langle Tu,v\rangle$ or is there something simpler?

Comment: @GBA It is bounded, because we are working on the spectrum which is compact.

Comment: Also no need to use spectral measures. You can just classical continuous functional calculus.